# The source of the story of GR"A and lashes

Tags: sources-mekorot, historical-figures, vilna-gaon, story-identification

> [It is worrisome to argue with the Gra about the different meanings of words, particularly after the famous (apocryphal?) story of him ordering lashes for the maskil who asserted to him that gila, rina, ditza, chedva, etcetera, were all complete synonyms.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8048/16706)

What is the source of this story?

Comment: [Is Josh Waxman on-topic?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/9682)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - The sefer הגאון החסיד מוילנא pg. רל - רלב. brings this story.

2 - According to this sefer, the reason the maskil got lashed by Beis Din, was because he degraded the words of Torah sages. He was disrespectful to the GR"a, but even more so, he made a disrespectful comment about Rashi.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So it wasn't because he thought certain Hebrew words were synonymous?

Comment: According to the story (ad loc.), the "maskil" also disputed the words of the Sages, who wrote that there are TEN different expressions of joy, one of them being "ditza". The "maskil" denied that "ditza" is an expression of joy.

Comment: @IsraelReader - They way I understood it,  it was his comment about Rashi that triggered the lashes. I"ll try to upload a copy soon.

Comment: You might want to check your source again. I am reading on page 231: הלא רבותינו הקדושים, בעלי המדרש, פירטו עשרה לשונות של שמחה, ובכללם דיצה. ובו ברגע הסיב הגר"א פניו הימנו

Comment: The story continues with the members of the Beis Din saying to him: האתה זה אשר חרפת וגדפת על *חכמי המדרש* ועל דברת רבינו

Comment: Looks like he was lashed for saying Rashi didn't explain the Pshat of the word

Comment: @IsraelReader - I"m not denying that there was an aspect of going against the Gr"a, but the on pg. רכ"ט he points out that he is writing this story about someone "who spoke against the words of  Chazal.

Comment: "who spoke against the words of Chazal" is in line with what I also from p. 231, אשר חרפת וגדפת על חכמי המדרש. These quotes are contrary to what you posited in an earlier comment, "it was his comment about Rashi that triggered the lashes".